# Why is Sidebar Showing at Bottom of Pages?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, layout, sidebar

How can I get the sidebar to show on right side of the page using twitter bootstrap. The header is properly placed.

What do you think the problem is, besides my incompetence?

Thanks for your help!

**application.html.erb**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Personal Control Center</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  <!-- Tells app to be mobile responsive -->
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-xs-12 .col-md-8">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 .col-md-4">
        <h2>About Us</h2><p>This app is for tracking and sharing habits, goals, values, and progress.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Github**: https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid. If you take up all 12 columns with other resources then it wont have space to be displayed. If you want to use a sidebar put your other resources in their own column of maybe 9-col-md and you can put your sidebar in a 3-col-md. like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Personal Control Center</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        <!-- Tells app to be mobile responsive -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container col-md-3>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  </div>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="container col-md-9">
      <div class="col-xs-12 .col-md-8">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 .col-md-4">
        <h2>About Us</h2><p>This app is for tracking and sharing habits, goals, values, and progress.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you can see from this example you are just placing your other columns within another column. that should work. (not tested) for more info check out their guides- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid